# Woocommerce custom countries sorting in checkout field front end

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to change the order of the countries in front end - woocommerce checkout country field.
I'd like to show specific countries first.
Found some php code for it, but it doesnt seem to work to me.
Any help/guidance much appreciated

here is what i tried

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_sort_countries', '__return_false' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_countries',  'handsome_bearded_guy_add_my_country' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_continents', 'handsome_bearded_guy_add_my_country_to_continents' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_countries',  'wc_custom_countries_order', 10, 1 );
function handsome_bearded_guy_add_my_country( $countries ) {
  $new_countries = array(
                        'CENTRAL'  => __( 'CanaLine.gr', 'woocommerce' ),
                        'ToumpaSKG'  => __( 'CanaLine Τούμπας (SKG)', 'woocommerce' ),
                        'HlioupoliSKG'  => __( 'CanaLine Ηλιούπολης (SKG)', 'woocommerce' ),
                        'ArgiroupoliATH'  => __( 'CanaLine Αργυρούπολης (ATH)', 'woocommerce' ),
                        'KavalaKAV'  => __( 'CanaLine Καβάλας (KAV)', 'woocommerce' ),
                        );

    return array_merge( $countries, $new_countries );
}
function handsome_bearded_guy_add_my_country_to_continents( $continents ) {
    $continents['EU']['countries'][] = 'CENTRAL';
    $continents['EU']['countries'][] = 'ToumpaSKG';
    $continents['EU']['countries'][] = 'HlioupoliSKG';
    $continents['EU']['countries'][] = 'ArgiroupoliATH';
    $continents['EU']['countries'][] = 'KavalaKAV';
    return $continents;
}
function wc_custom_countries_order( $countries ) {
  // replace with iso code of the country (example: US or GB)

     unset($countries['CENTRAL']);
     unset($countries['ToumpaSKG']);
     unset($countries['HlioupoliSKG']);
     unset($countries['ArgiroupoliATH']);
     unset($countries['KavalaKAV']);
  // replace with iso code of country AND country name (example: US | United States or GB | United Kingdom (UK)
  $countries = ['CENTRAL' => 'CanaLine.gr'] + ['ToumpaSKG' => 'CanaLine Τούμπας (SKG)'] + ['HlioupoliSKG' => 'CanaLine Ηλιούπολης (SKG)'] + ['ArgiroupoliATH' => 'CanaLine Αργυρούπολης (ATH)'] + ['KavalaKAV' => 'CanaLine Καβάλας (KAV)] +$countries;
    
  return $countries;
}
```

Comment: Looks fine for me. I have tested it and worked fine. your defined countries are working for me.

Comment: At your side, they appear first in the list, followed by the rest of the countries? I just tried it on another wordpress site and still they dont get to the top of the list,, cant bypass the default sorting system ...

Comment: I think i made a mistake with the code, trying to make it as an example code.. But i think the Country1-5 is being sorted by WC default sorting, the same way so it wasnt actually testing if it worked maybe..  I updated the code in the post to the one im actually using,,, if anyone can check/help..

Comment: At your side, they appear first in the list, followed by the rest of the countries? => Yes

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Try to add higher priorities.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_sort_countries', '__return_false', 999 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_continents', 'assign_countries_to_continent', 999 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_countries',  'wc_custom_countries_order', 999, 1 );

function assign_countries_to_continent( $continents ) {
    $continents['EU']['countries'][] = 'Country1';
    $continents['EU']['countries'][] = 'Country2';
    $continents['EU']['countries'][] = 'Country3';
    $continents['EU']['countries'][] = 'Country4';
    $continents['EU']['countries'][] = 'Country5';
    return $continents;
}

function wc_custom_countries_order( $countries ) {
    $countries = ['Country1' => 'Country  1'] + ['Country2' => 'Country  2'] + ['Country3' => 'Country  3'] + ['Country4' => 'Country  4'] + ['Country5' => 'Country  5'] + $countries;

    return $countries;
}
```

Comment: Tried it with priorities 999 like suggested, still the same :X , I need country 'Canaline GR 'showing first, followed by 'Canaline Toumpas' etc like in code, but it doesnt get sorted for some reason xx

Comment: For example if i swap Country 1 with Country 2, it will still show Country 1 first :X

Comment: Thank you very much Bhautik for fixing^^